# undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x0000010484b2c8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.  I am trying to use will_paginate and bootstrap-will_paginate to include pagination on the index portion of my Users controller.  I installed the above gems.

The code that is complaining is here:

```
  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Is there any reason you see why this is failing?

Comment: Have you included them gem in your gemfile and ran bundle install, and, just for good measure, restarted the server?

Comment: restarting the server was the issue.  whoops.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
@users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

it should work. Hope to be helpfull